# Insert TextBox Value in Database

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I use the following code to save a TextBox value into the database.  However, when I insert the value it will save in a new row.  How can I save it to the same row?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pass = textBox1.Text;
    sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=P3;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = sql;
    cmd.CommandText = ("Insert [MyTable] ([MyColumn]) Values (@pass)");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
    sql.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql.Close();
}
```

Comment: How do you identify the record?

Answer (score 4):

Use an update command instead of insert.

```
cmd.CommandText = "update YourTable set FieldName = YourValue where KeyField = YourKeyValue"
```

Comment: Acutally, no I can't.  It won't let me edit my post for some reason... so I'll try to put it here.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "update YourTable set FieldName = YourValue where KeyField = YourKeyValue";

Answer (score 2):

You need to use UPDATE instead of INSERT similar to this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourColumn = newValue
WHERE (your criteria needs to go here) ID = recordId
```

You need to create the UPDATE statement for your record. If your intention is to UPDATE all then your statement would be:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourColumn = newValue
```

otherwise, you will want to tell it which records to UPDATE

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourColumn = newValue
WHERE ID = yourID

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pass = textBox1.Text;
    sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=P3;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = sql;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = @pass WHERE id=@id"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
    sql.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql.Close();
}
```

Here is a website with some samples explaining using ADO.NET:

[Simple ADO.NET Database Read, Insert, Update and Delete using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1155/Simple-ADO-NET-Database-Read-Insert-Update-and-Del)

[How to use UPDATE in ado net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772219/how-to-use-update-in-ado-net)

Comment: The WHERE is telling you that you will need to specify the correct row to update, otherwise you will update all rows which I don't think is your intention.

Comment: yes it will update all rows. how can i just update it for my intention row?

Comment: I already updated my answer, you need to pass in a second parameter telling it which row to update. I referenced another question on SO with an example

Comment: Are you not reading what everyone is telling you? This is basic SQL. You need to learn basic SQL before you go forward!!