# Syntax Error in UPDATE Statement - C#

Tags: c#

> I have been trying to update data to MSACCESS database from the GRIDVIEW..but while executing the ExecuteNonQuery statement i am getting an error that SYNTAX ERROR IN UPDATE STATEMENT. Please help me .... My problem might be similar to those posted by several people .. but my piece of code is different to that of others.. Please respond quickly... In the following code this is the line 
>           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); where i am receiving error...plz..plz help me

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();    
    string name = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["SName"].ToString();
    TextBox day = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
    string com = "update enroll set Day = '?' where SName = '?'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(com, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", day.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SName", name.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    Label3.Text = name + " Details Updated successfully";
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe **the specific problem** — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. [See SSCCE.org for guidance](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `OleDbParameter`s are positional not named.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772219/how-to-use-update-in-ado-net

Comment: what it the data type of `Day ` column in your database?

Comment: The data type of day column is varchar.... and the error is with cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 4):

change `string com = "update enroll set Day = '?' where SName = '?'";`

to

```
string com = "update enroll set Day = ? where SName = ?";
```

since you have quotes before and after `?` it will not consider as parameter

Comment: Thanks for your response...I did as you said ...but still not rectified

Comment: is there any error? or can't see the changes in your database?